# Check value from Gravity Forms API

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, gravity-forms-plugin

I am creating a custom Gravity Forms add-on and it appears to work so far. The settings are showing and saving as expected.

[image]

Here's what I have:

```
public function plugin_settings_fields() {

    return array(
        array(
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Animal Types', 'animaltypes' ),
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'gravity_forms_animal_types',
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'label' => esc_html__( 'Animal Types', 'animaltypes' ),
                    'choices' => array(
                        array(
                            'label' => esc_html__( 'Cat', 'animaltypes' ),
                            'name' => 'option_cat',
                            'default_value' => 0,
                        ),
                        array(
                            'label' => esc_html__( 'Dogs', 'animaltypes' ),
                            'name' => 'option_dog',
                            'default_value' => 0,
                        )
                    )
                ),
            )
        )
    );
}
```

But what I can't figure out is how to check, for example, if `option_cat` has been set so that I can then run a custom function if it is.

So essentially (and I know the below code is not correct) something like this:

```
if(option_cat == true) {
    my_cat_function();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite simple after all.

```
$options = get_option('gravityformsaddon_animaltypes_settings');
$cat     = $options['option_cat'];


if($cat) {
    my_cat_function();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In gravity forms when you create a new addon you provide a slug for that addon. Gravity forms save that settings with the help of that slug.

So if you want to get that settings you can use below code.

```
$settings = get_option('gravityformsaddon_slugname__settings');
$option = rgar( $settings, 'gravity_forms_animal_types' );
```

In options you can get selection of your settings, and if you want to one selection at a time you must use radio button instead of checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. So I do have a slug of course. This gets me closer but I get an **Illegal string offset 'option_cat'** warning.

    `$settings = get_option('gravityformsaddon_animaltypes_settings'); 
    $options = rgar( $settings, 'gravity_forms_animal_types' ); 
    $cat = $options['option_cat']; 
    if($cat) { 
        my_cat_function(); 
    }`

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: If this answer help you can you please upvote my answer.